# Android Opencv complement color calculation

Tags: android, opencv

I am trying to write Android application , which tries to calculate a complement color for a user touched region, i calculated the complement color using only hue values in that region,i haven't included the saturation & value channels. in which situations these channels are useful??.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer Here to calculate complimentary color calculation.
http://serennu.com/colour/rgbtohsl.php

You can cross check with the implementation with this site. here direct opposite colors in the wheel is complimentary to each other

http://paletton.com/#uid=1000u0kllllaFw0g0qFqFg0w0aF